# How To Fit Number of ImageViews Inside RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a fixed Dimension-Ratio

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="35:16"
        ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I Need to show list of `ImageView` inside the `RecyclerView`, but with a fixed number of images shown on the screen, and the rest of the images need to scroll to be shown, similar to the image

[image]

I Create this layout with `ImageView` inside it:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*The problem here*

I try a lot, but the image doesn't show without setting the `layout_width` and `layout_hieght` with a fixed number.
and What i want is to set `ImageView` hight-width **dynamicly** with **`RecyclerView` Hight** and **Screen Width**.

Comment: You'll have to provide specific height for that. If you want square images, then you can make a custom view by extending 'view' property which will keep your image height as much as the width you provide & vice versa.

Comment: did you try scaletype fitXY ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is super easy:

pass `DisplayMetrics` In The Adapter Constructor for getting screen width.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
public SearchSliderOneAdapter(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
        this.displayMetrics = displayMetrics;
}
```

and calculate the width of *`ImageView` = ScreenWidth\numberOfImage* inside `onCreateViewHolder` function of the adapter.

```
public SearchSliderOneViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_image_slider, parent, false);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                displayMetrics.widthPixels / numberOfImage,
                GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        inflate.setLayoutParams(params);
        return new SearchSliderOneViewHolder(inflate, listener);
}
```