# Create the Recycler view with fixed item count in horizontal scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Please help Me,

I am trying to create a specific type of recycler view which can have always 3 items in all kind of mobile phone. Whether that mobile is having 4 inch display or 6.5 inch display.

Please tell me if that is possible or not.

my code of xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/recomended"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/graycurverdbtn"
    android:layout_height="170dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/mountain">

    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"


        >

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/pinkbtn"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/pinkcurvedbtn"
            android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Recomended"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="9dp">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_margin="8dp"
     >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Pest control">

            </TextView>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"></View>
            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/shopname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="K02BgbhdAf">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/graylocation"
                android:text="Airport Road"
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal">

            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Adapter code

```
public class OurrecomendedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OurrecomendedAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<HomeResponse.Recommend> ourrecomendedlist = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    public static int recomendedid=0;
    public OurrecomendedAdapter(List<HomeResponse.Recommend> list, Context context) {
        this.ourrecomendedlist = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recomemdedservices_item, parent, false);
//        itemView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) (parent.getWidth() * 0.3),ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        holder.title.setText(ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getCategory().getSlug());
        holder.shopname.setText(ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getCategory().getName());

        Picasso.get().load(ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image, new Callback() {
            @Override
           public void onSuccess() {

           }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

            }
        });
        holder.recomended.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getCategory().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("salon for women") || ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getCategory().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("salon for men")){

                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
                    WomensalonlistFragment subc = new WomensalonlistFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("id", ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getProductcategoryId().toString());
                    args.putString("title", ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getName());
                    subc.setArguments(args);

                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).
                            replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, subc).commit();
                }
                else
                {

                    typeListid= ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getId().toString();
                    Intent intent= new Intent(context, ProductdetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("productId",typeListid);
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                    HomeFragment.vendormainid=ourrecomendedlist.get(position).getId().toString();

                }


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.ourrecomendedlist.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name,title,shopname,address,pinkbtn;
        Button addtocart;
        ImageView image;
        RelativeLayout recomended;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            addtocart=itemView.findViewById(R.id.addtocart);

            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            shopname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopname);
            address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            recomended=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recomended);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            pinkbtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pinkbtn);



        }

    }
}
```

in this i need to display our output as 3 items in each aspect-ratio mobile.
but I'm unable to achieve that. If I'm opening in big screen mobile then it's showing 3.5 items and in small device some times it's showing 2.75 items.

Kindly help me in that how to achieve that exact output.

Comment: Dude it is necessary use a RecyclerView or what about of LinearLayout orientation horizontal, and 3 views inside of it. Is possible use RecyclerView but i think the LinearLayout adjust better for your case

Comment: I think you mean fit three items on the screen but you still have other ones inside the `RecyclerView`,  I had the same issue in the past so look at my question it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509294/how-to-fit-number-of-imageviews-inside-recyclerview

Comment: @AimanAlyosofi actually in different different screen size that item count is varying 2.5,3&3.5 items like that

Comment: @AlbertoVazquez without Recycler view how can we call dynamic data in that.